# Ubuntu 18.04 no installation or update after upgrade from 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, package-management, upgrade, python3

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 series, which shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled. I can't upgrade, install or uninstall nothing in Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrade it from 16.04.

When I upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 the process has some errors (problems with the kernel), previously I had upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and I had errors with that upgrade too, but I solved them.

Now, when I try to upgrade, install or uninstall some program, I get these results:

```
rafmsl@rafmsl ~> sudo apt upgrade
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt --fix-broken install» para corregirlo.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
  2to3 : Depende: python3-lib2to3 (>= 3.6.7-1~) pero no está instalado
  idle : Depende: idle-python3.6 pero no está instalado
  libglib2.0-dev-bin : Depende: python3-distutils pero no está instalado
  python3-distutils-extra : Depende: python3-distutils pero no está instalado
  E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt --fix-broken install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
rafmsl@rafmsl ~> sudo apt --fix-broken install
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Corrigiendo dependencias... Listo
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  comerr-dev gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0
  icu-devtools imagemagick-common krb5-multidev libamd2.4.1
  libcolamd2.9.1 libcryptsetup4 libfcitx-gclient0 libglpk36
  libgraphite2-dev libgssrpc4 libharfbuzz-gobject0 libicu-le-hb0
  libiculx60 libkadm5clnt-mit11 libkadm5srv-mit11 libkdb5-9
  libmozjs-24-0v5 libnma-common libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5
  libsuitesparseconfig4.4.6 libxapian22v5 libxcb-xf86dri0 pkg-config
  s-nail ttf-ubuntu-font-family
Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  idle-python3.6 python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  idle-python3.6 python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
0 actualizados, 3 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 312 no actualizados.
8 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se necesita descargar 0 B/474 kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 3,394 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] S
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 364281 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../python3-lib2to3_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando python3-lib2to3 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir `/usr/lib/python3.6/lib2to3/Grammar.txt', que está también en el paquete libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 3.6.7-1+trusty1
dpkg-deb: error: copiado el subproceso fue asesinado por la señal (Tubería rota)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../idle-python3.6_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando idle-python3.6 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir `/usr/lib/python3.6/idlelib/CREDITS.txt', que está también en el paquete libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 3.6.7-1+trusty1
dpkg-deb: error: copiado el subproceso fue asesinado por la señal (Tubería rota)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../python3-distutils_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando python3-distutils (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir `/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/README', que está también en el paquete libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 3.6.7-1+trusty1
dpkg-deb: error: copiado el subproceso fue asesinado por la señal (Tubería rota)
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/idle-python3.6_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.6.7-1~18.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Maybe this can help too:

```
rafmsl@rafmsl ~> df -h
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
udev             1.9G      0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs            386M   1.9M  384M   1% /run
/dev/sda4        141G    64G   70G  48% /
tmpfs            1.9G    84M  1.8G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M   4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1.9G      0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        496M    19M  478M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs            386M    24K  386M   1% /run/user/118
tmpfs            386M   700K  385M   1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Thank you so much @N0rbert, no I can work normally.